# ListPoinPlot3D works but ListPlot3D does not

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I don't understand what is going on. The same table, plotted with the tool `ListPointPlot3D` gives the desired output. But plotted with `ListPlot3D` gives an empty box. I repeat, **the data is exactly the same**, and is organized in the form `{{x1,y1,f[x1,y1]},{x2,y2,f[x2,y2]},.....}`, but plotted with the environment `ListPointPlot3D` gives a correct output, while plotted with `ListPlot3D` gives an empty box:

[image: data plotted using <code>ListPointPlot3D</code>]

[image: data plotted using <code>ListPlot3D</code>]

After many proofs, it seems to be related with the numerical precision. But I am not an expert at all, so I can not say the reason. I will add a reduced example to illustrate the problem. Consider the table:

```
data = {{191716.2098765432, 1.521303561654648, 
1.}, {191716.2098765432, 1.521317429495046, 
0.9889006624084674}, {191716.2098765432, 1.5213312973354443, 
0.9727962635189932}, {191716.2098765432, 1.5213451651758423, 
0.9436508829153076}, {191716.2098765432, 1.5213590330162405, 
0.918350312853329}, {314303.5185185185, 1.521303561654648, 
1.}, {314303.5185185185, 1.521317429495046, 
0.9972031750900022}, {314303.5185185185, 1.5213312973354443, 
0.9841391548184985}, {314303.5185185185, 1.5213451651758423, 
0.9610087555954755}, {314303.5185185185, 1.5213590330162405, 
0.9359559956477607}, {477237.11111111107, 1.521303561654648, 
1.}, {477237.11111111107, 1.521317429495046, 
0.9951462414500726}, {477237.11111111107, 1.5213312973354443, 
0.9884845310861505}, {477237.11111111107, 1.5213451651758423, 
0.9681551444835496}, {477237.11111111107, 1.5213590330162405, 
0.9457419133525969}};
```

If I try to plot this table, using the command `ListPlot3D[data]`, I get an empty box. Now, if I modify the data like this:

```
data2 = Table[{data[[i, 1]]/1000, data[[i, 2]]*1000,data[[i, 3]]},{i, 1, Length[data]}]
```

The same identical command (`ListPlot3D[data2]`) gives me this output:

[image]

If I don't divide/multiply by 1000, but by, for example, 100, it gives back the empty box again. This is so strange. What might be the reason? and How can this be avoided?

Thank you very much

Comment: Without a minimal example (code and data) showing the problem, we cannot say what is occurring.

Comment: for the latter to work the sampling in {x,y} must represent a regular grid.

Comment: Thank you Bob and Chris. I added a reduced example of what's going on. I made some proofs and it seems that the command works also for irregular grids (look the added lines in the post).

Comment: The problem seems to be that the y range of your data is very small, causing `ListPlot3D` to fail in scaling the plot ranges. Your solution of rescaling the y range before plotting is probably the best workaround.

Comment: Yes but if i multiply only the y coordinate by 1000, and leave unaltered x, it does not plot it anyway.